# What compilers support CUDA

Tags: visual-studio-2010, compiler-construction, cuda, dev-c++

I found some problem with Visual Studio. My project that use `openMP` multithreading was twice slow on Visual Studio 2010, than on Dev-C++ , Now I wrote my other project that uses CUDA technology , I think that my project works slow because of Visual Studio, so I need some other compiler that will support CUDA , my questions are:

1. is Dev-C++ support CUDA?
2. what compilers support CUDA except Visual Studio?
3. if there are a lot compilers supporting CUDA what will give best speed for application?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The CUDA Toolkit [Release Notes](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-toolkit-release-notes/index.html) list the supported platforms and compilers.

Comment: Thank you very much, as I saw  Supported Windows Compilers on the windows only Visual Studio 2008 and 2010. But there are many compilers on the Linux , My question is will be there program speed difference between Windows and Linux compilers?

Comment: Yes, all compilers are different, and will generate code that is slightly different.  Therefore there will be program speed differences.  In the case of device code, the underlying device code compiler that nvcc uses should be the same, but even then system-level differences between linux and windows will affect overall program speed.  I believe Greg has answered your 3 questions: 1. no Dev-C++ is not supported. 2. For windows, the only supported compiler is cl.exe, which is included in VS. 3. This is an unanswerable question.

Answer (score 0):

Well I think it's the other way around. The thing is, there is a driver called `nvcc`. it generates device code and host code and sends the host code to a compiler. It should be a C compiler and it should be in the executable path. (EDIT: and it should be gcc on Linux and cl on Windows and I think I should ignore mac as the release note did(?))

nvcc Compiler Info reads:

> A general purpose C compiler is needed by nvcc in the following
> situations:
>
> 1. During non-CUDA phases (except the run phase), because these phases will be forwarded by nvcc to this compiler
> 2. During CUDA phases, for several preprocessing stages (see also 0). On Linux platforms, the compiler is assumed to be ‘gcc’, or ‘g++’ for linking. On Windows platforms, the  compiler is assumed to be ‘cl’. The
>    compiler executables are expected to be in the current executable
>    search path, unless option -compiler-bin-dir is specified, in which
>    case the value of this option must be the name of the directory in
>    which these compiler executables reside.

And please don't talk like that about compilers. Your code is in a way that works better with Dev-C++. What is generated is an assembly code. I don't say that they don't make any difference, but maybe 4 to 5%, not 100%.

And absolutely definitely don't blame the compiler for your slow program. It is definitely because of inefficient memory access and incorrect use of different types of memory.